# Получение прикреплённых файлов из письма postfix

Tags: postfix

Начал изучать почтовый сервер Postfix. Со всем разобрался кроме прикреплённых файлов. Отправил с другой почты к себе на сервер пнгшную картинку и она пришла закодированным текстом, типо

```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...
```

Скажите, как можно раскодировать прикреплённые файлы и сохранить их в папку?